# Spark Executor low performance while writing a dataframe to parquet

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, apache-spark-2.0

Spark version : 2.3
hadoop dist : azure Hdinsight 2.6.5
Platform : Azure
Storage : BLOB

Nodes in the cluster: 6
Executor instances : 6
cores per executor : 3
Memory per executor : 8gb

Trying to load a csv file(size 4.5g - 280 col , 2.8 mil rows ) in azure blob (wasb) to parquet format via a spark dataframe on the same storage account. I have repartitioned the file with different size i.e. 20, 40, 60, 100 but facing a weird issue where the 2 out of the 6 executors that process a very small subset of records ( < 1%) keep running for an 1 hour or so and eventually complete.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Question :

1) the partitions that is getting processed by these 2 executors has the least records to process ( less than 1%) but take almost an hour to complete. what is the reason for this. Is this opposite of a data skew scenario ?

2) local cache folders on the nodes running these executors are getting filled up (50-60GB). Not sure of the reason behind this.

3) Increasing the partitions does bring the over all execution time down to 40 min but wanted to know the reason behind the low through with these 2 executors only.

New to spark so looking forward to some pointers to tune this workload. Additonal info from Spark WebUi attached.

Answer (score 0):

What hadoop cluster environment are you using ?

1) 
Ans : Are you sing partitionColumnBy while writing the file? else try it and check.

2) 
Ans : Increase the number of partitions i.e. use "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions"

3) 
Ans : Need more specific information like sample data and etc. to give answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22247476)

Comment: @LucaKiebel Reputation does not linked anyway to answer. If it is sufficient answer or not questioner would let us know.